# How do I fetch match a WHERE clause across multiple rows of the same table?

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables `question` and `tag`, with 1 row in question table having potentially more than tags in the tag table.

The table might look like:

```
    question
    ---------
    id | subject
    ------------
    1  |  foo


    tag
    ------------------------------
    id  |  name  |   question_id
    ------------------------------
    1   | bar    |    1
    2   | abc    |    1
    3   | bar    |    2
```

*What I am trying to get is questions which have *all* specified tags.* So in the above case I want to query to get the "foo" question when I pass bar and abc as the tags.

The `IN` clause obviously won't work in this case since it will return the "foo" question if it has either bar or abc as tags:

```
select q.* from question q
where q.id in (select t.question_id from tag t where t.name in ('bar', 'abc'));
```

Can someone help me with coming up with the right query?

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. "question_id". Single quotes are for string literals, e.g. 'bar'.

Comment: Sorry, that was pseudo query which I just made up. You are right about the single quotes, thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed the question to use the right quotes in the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and `having`:

```
select question_id
from tag
where name in ('abc', 'bar')
group by question_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

```
select q.subject, 
from question q
  join tag t on q.id = t.question_id
group by q.subject
having count(distinct t.name) = (select count(distinct name) from tag)
```

List a subject if it has all tags, no matter how many different tags there are.